# .distinct not returning unique entries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a table of Projects, in that table, there may be the same project multiple times with the same name, however the created_at month will be different. I'm trying to select the most recent record of each project in my table. Using select works, however I need the entire record so that then I can loop through the records and print out different attributes eg price or what not.

I've tried:

**Project.distinct(:project_name)** – Prints all records (to check this I copied the project name and did a find and all projects with the identical name would still print out)

**Project.order(project_name: :asc, created_at: :desc).uniq(:project_name)** – Same result as above

**Project.select(:project_name).distinct** – Pulls only 1 of each, however it only selects the project name and no other data from the record.

Comment: Correct, `.select` only grabs the listed field names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the case where [DISTINCT ON](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) comes to rescue.

This should work:

```
Project.select("DISTINCT ON (project_name) *").order("project_name, created_at DESC")
```

for selecting only particular columns specify them instead of `*`.

```
Project.select("DISTINCT ON (project_name) project_name, created_at, price").order("project_name, created_at DESC")
```

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks Dnsh. What's odd now is that, after creating the var my_projects to store the selected projects, I call .sum(:budget_margin) – and instead of adding up just those projects, it still adds up everything. I looped through the columns and the var only contained the unique project so I have no idea how it's getting all projects instead and adding them up.